# Debugging badaWAC application

Tags: javascript, bada

I'm develop web app for `bada` platform using `badaWAC` api. What are the ways to debug `badaWAC` application? May be exists some browser plugin for this target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this on your desktop browser, which offers a richer set of debugging tools, such as [Chrome’s Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview/). This is where [PhoneGap Emulation](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) steps-in.

With your Google Chrome desktop browser, you can emulate PhoneGap’s JavaScript APIs. This includes everything from the deviceready event to navigator.device.capture to your custom plugins. By leveraging your desktop browser, you can speed up your initial development process and quickly debug the DOM, JavaScript, and resource loading.

It’s important to understand that PhoneGap Emulation only applies to JavaScript. While the emulator will use a device skin, it cannot emulate the rendering capabilities of a specific mobile platform browser.

If you just wish to step into and debug javascript via the browser you can do it easly via [this tool](http://debug.phonegap.com/), which acts like google's debugging tool.